# confusing behavior of tuple unpacking -- for loop on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
I have a list of tuples `data`:

data =[(array([[2, 1, 3]]), array([1])),
 (array([[2, 1, 2]]), array([1])),
 (array([[4, 4, 4]]), array([0])),
 (array([[4, 1, 1]]), array([0])),
 (array([[4, 4, 3]]), array([0]))]
```

For simplicity's sake, this list here only has 5 tuples.

When I run the following code, it seem I am able to unpack each tuple with
each iteration:

```
for x,y in data2:
    print(x,y)


output:

[[2 1 3]] [1]
[[2 1 2]] [1]
[[4 4 4]] [0]
[[4 1 1]] [0]
[[4 4 3]] [0]


This also works:

for x,y in data2[:2]:
    print(x,y)


output:

[[2 1 3]] [1]
[[2 1 2]] [1]


However, when I take only a single tuple from the list:

for x,y in data2[0]:
    print(x,y)


output: 
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-185-1eed1fccdb3a> in <module>()
----> 1 for x,y in data2[0]:
      2     print(x,y)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I'm confused as to how tuples are being unpacked in the earlier cases, that are
preventing the last case to also successfully unpack the tuples.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I don't have a desired output as much, I was trying to understand the behavior of the first two instances.  It seems x,y was able to separate each tuple of the list, when iterating, but when given only one tuple it wasn't able to separate them. I wanted to know what the first two instances were doing, so as to efficiently use loops with list of tuples as well as prevent future bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first two cases you're looping through `list`, in the last one you're accessing `tuple`

Not sure what you want to achieve, but instead of `data[0]`, `data[:1]` would work.

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this:

```
data =[([[2, 1, 3]], [1]),
([[2, 1, 2]], [1]),
([[4, 4, 4]]), [0]),
([[4, 1, 1]], [0]),
([[4, 4, 3]], [0])]

for [a], b in data:
    print a, b
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3] [1]
[2, 1, 2] [1]
[4, 4, 4] [0]
[4, 1, 1] [0]
[4, 4, 3] [0]
```